# How To Version My Custom Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, versioning

I have written some custom classes for coredata for use in projects.  These will be updated over time.

Besides using git, what is the best way to manage versioning for my custom classes in my iOS projects?

Comment: Custom classes or core-data model? You can create separate versioned core-data models apart from the source control for your project.

Comment: @Rakesh I know how to version core-data model.  I am asking how to version my custom classes without using git.  These are for any custom classes (I mentioned core-data in the question because that is a custom class that I am currently working on).

Comment: Well, if its not versioning for your model, then its basic source control functionality right? git or svn or the like will be more than sufficient. why not git? And by custom classes for core-data do you mean the NSManagedObject sublcass?

Comment: @Rakesh Yes. It is.  I am asking how to do it locally in my projects without git?  I'm not implying there's anything wrong with using git.  I am asking for alternative methods.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to do source control without a SCM system. But i think you can find what you want (it still uses an SCM)from the accepted answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822233/how-to-maintain-separate-svn-repositories-for-the-same-project . It uses svn but it's applicable to git too. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nice new feature In Xcode4.x for version control, you can take help of that in order to achieve that.

For details on it: Check this link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/000-About_Xcode/about.html

Comment: This is the function I would, and do, use.